# Output class of each element in array after getting user input, Ruby

Tags: ruby, each

I have a little program accepting user input of multiple integers separated by whitespace, ex: `4 5 6 7`

I then push this into an array and want to find the class of each element in the array, which I expect to be a string since I am using the gets command. I am using the .each iterator to do this, but in my code below when I `puts output.class` I get one output of array instead of four outputs of string.

Can someone point out what I am doing wrong here?

```
values = []

puts "enter segment values separated by spaces: "
entry = gets.split
values << entry


values.each do |output|
    puts output.class
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`entry` is an array, and hence, `values` array contains only one element which happens to be `entry` array.

To fix the issue, you can replace `values << entry` with:

```
values.push *entry
```

---

*Explanation*

`Array#<<` method pushes a single object into the array.  In your case, you were pushing `entry` array, hence, it got pushed as single element.

If you want to push each individual element of `entry` array, then, use of splat operator (`*`) will allow us to convert an array into multiple arguments to a method.  Unfortunately, `<<` takes single argument, and will error out if we do:

```
values << *entry
#=> main.rb:5: syntax error, unexpected *
#    values << *entry
               ^
```

There is another method, `Array#push`, which can be passed variable number of objects and it will push each one into the array.  So, final code will look like:

```
values.push *entry
```

Comment: Your suggestion is correct, but there is no need to change `<<` into `push` at the same time. That is confusing.

Comment: @sawa - It gives me an error (`syntax error, unexpected *`) when I do `values << *entry`, so I tried `push`

Comment: I see. But you better explain that.

Comment: Thank you both for your help :)

Comment: Alternatively, you can do `values.concat(entry)`.